# UseEffect no se ejecuta al cambiar una propiedad

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código en ReactJS:

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(LabelerContext);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("DISPARANDO USEEFFECT")
    }, [state.timer.stop])
```

Pero el useEffect no funciona cuando se cambia la propiedad que necesito, que es stop.
El objeto de mi estado luce así:

```
const initialState = { timer: { time: 0,  initialTime: 0, stop: true  } };
```

El useEffect sólo se está ejecutando cuando se monta el componente pero no cuando se cambia la propiedad. ¿A qué se puede deber esto? ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute el useEffect cuando cambie la propiedad stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo que no escribes aquí causa que el `useEffect` no se actualice.

Aquí tienes una [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-gates-35v8h?file=/src/components/Hola.js) que funciona. `stop` se actualiza cuando haces clic en el botón y `useEffect` se imprime el `console.log` con el nuevo estado.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta lo que comentas, acabo de probar cambiando true por 'true' y false por 'false'. De esta forma funcionó, pero aún así tengo la curiosidad de qué puede estar pasando